# Run a text formula in an adjacent cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having trouble trying to figure out a way to have two columns, one to show the entire formula that can be editable and the second to actually perform the formula.

Ideally, I would like my sheet to be set up like this:

```
Formula | Value
=5+2    | 7
=3-2    | 1
```

I would like to be able to change the Formula column and have it automatically update the Value column.

I've tried using the `GetFormula()` function but I don't think that's what I want to do as I would end up in a circular reference based on what I want to do. The closest I've got is using a `Right()` function and Text in the formula column or a space and removing the space. However, I end up with the text and not the solved formula instead.

Using `=RIGHT(A2, LEN(A2)-1)`

```
Formula | Value
 =5+2   | =5+2
```

I have also tried using `=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-1)` but without the "=" and can't figure out how to convert the "5+2" into text that I can use to solve. I'm hoping to do this with a formula and without a macro/VBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do it.

## 1

Open the Name Manager. Control-F3 from the worksheet, and then click the New button.

## 2

For the Name field in the dialog, enter `EVALA`. I just picked this name; it stands for "Evaluate A". But you can pick whatever name you like.

## 3

For the `Refers to` field, enter this

```
=EVALUATE($A1)
```

## 4

Click OK and then Close.

## 5

In B1 enter this formula:

```
=EVALA
```

That's it.

You can now use this formula on any row in the worksheet and it will evaluate whatever is in the column A cell of the row where you enter the formula.

Comment: So you can use Evaluate in Excel, *except* in a cell formula?

Comment: I was going to use `=Evaluate` to try and use a formula to solve the problem...but it doesn't exist when I start typing `=Evalu...`.  But I see you used it in the Name Manager...so can you just not use it in a cell, but you can elsewhere? (I thought it was mainly a VBA function).

Comment: There are two completely different and unrelated Evaluate functions. There is one in VBA and it is available as methods from the Application, Worksheet, and Chart objects. The one I am using here is from the ancient macro language called XLM4. It predates VBA. Some XLM4 functions can be used in the Name Manager. None can be used in cells.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a user defined function easily enough with VBA, but if you don't regularly use VBA then an alternative method is to create a Name object.  Name objects can access certain functions not typically available in a cell's formula. One of these functions is "Evaluate" which will evaluate a string as a mathematical expression. Here's a demonstration how to do this.

**NOTE:**  Pay special attention to the use of `$`.  Chances are you don't want any `$` in your name definition since that will prevent it from behaving in a relative manner.  Also, `Sheet1!` means that this will not work on another sheet.

**Update** I just want to give credit for this method to the following sources.  This is pretty neat stuff, so for anyone interested give it a read. The last link in particular gives a neat example of creating a chart with no data points.

[MSDN Evaluating Defined Names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb687836(v=office.12).aspx)
[The power of evaluate (ozgrid)](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=52372)
[XL4 Macro Functions in Names - JKP](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/excelnames08.asp)
[Evaluate and Indirect](http://www.vertex42.com/ExcelArticles/evaluate-function.html)
[More unique functionality of Defined Names](https://www.sumproduct.com/thought/evaluating-evaluate.html)

[image]

This is probably the best solution for the OP, since it asks to avoid using VBA; however, this method is somewhat limited. It requires manual set-up on every sheet to be used.  Much preferable I think is to create a very simple UDF like this...

```
Function Eval(Expr As String)
    Eval = Application.Evaluate(Expr)
End Function
```

This can be added to any accessible add-in, making it available to any instance of Excel.  A little more set-up, but less maintenance.

Comment: Duplicate answer. Please remove.

Comment: @ExcelHero I don't think independently posting (very close times) the same method with different details and different presentations constitutes a duplicate. Especially if one post is presented as a step-by-step and the other as a visual (since ideally an answer board will have both).  I honestly don't see the value in removing this post.  However, I did add more information to compare the Name method with the VBA method, since I do think there are legitimate reasons to favor the later over the former.

Comment: What are Name Objects? Are you referring to Defined Names?

Comment: @ExcelHero Yea, Defined Name is probably the better term in general Excel speak. I'm just used to programming so I think of them as objects :P

Answer (score 0):

Just put a single `'` before the formula in your A column:
`'=5+2` will show in your cell as "=5+2". Then in the B column, just do the formula as normal, `=5+2`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm hoping that B1 auto updates as A1 is updated. This being so I could update A1 and see the result in B1 as I update it. So, in your scenario, if I change A1 to =5+3, B would change to 8, rather than 7. I'm wondering if I can use `value()` at all to make this work.

Comment: @medavis6 - Ah, I'll see what else I can do.  How opposed to VBA solution are you? There's a quick one, but if you'd really rather not, then I'll work on a formula still.

Comment: I'd like to avoid VBA, if possible. Thanks!